# Lua matching a 16 long hex with a prefix

Tags: lua

Let's say I have the string `/url/ID0123456789abcdef/bar`. I want to find and/or replace the `ID0123456789abcdef`. This ID is always of the form of 2 alphabets, followed by 16 hex.

This is what I've done, and not sure if this is the best solution:

```
function replace_id(str, prefix, replace)
    local first, last = str:find(prefix)
    if first == nil then
        return str
    end

    local hex = str:sub(last - 1, last + 16)
    if not is_hex(hex) then
        return str
    end

    return replace_id(str:gsub(hex, replace), prefix, replace)
end

function utils.is_hex(str)
    if utils.is_str_empty(str) then
        return false
    end

    -- String is alphanumeric and hex
    return str:gsub('%a', ''):gsub('%d', '') == '' and str:gsub('%x', '') == ''
end

print(replace_id('/url/ID0123456789abcdef/bar', 'ID', 'REPLACED'))
-- Prints '/url/REPLACED/bar'
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `str:gsub('ID'..("%w"):rep(16), 'REPLACED')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making things way harder than you need to.

A single call to `string.gsub()` does what you want and all you need to do is build a pattern for what you want to match, which is quite easy.

The only thing to consider, if you wanted to build a pattern that contained *magic* characters like `%` or `.` you'd have to escape them first, which isn't that hard either, but that seems to not apply to your case anyway, as your prefix is only alphabetical characters.

```
function foo(str, prefix, replacement)
  return str:gsub(prefix..string.rep("%x", 16), replacement)
end
```

This should do what you want just fine.

`string.rep("%x", 16)`, as the name suggests, repeats the string 16 times, building a Lua pattern that matches 16 hexadecimal digits.